# How can I avoid uniroot error that stops the loop?

Tags: r, try-catch, uniroot

I am running `uniroot` function in the loop, but hit an error and the code stopped. The code is as below;

```
func <-function(f) -a*b/c*0.5*d*e^2 + (d/f-1)*g*sin(h*(pi/180))-i
dat <- data.frame(a = c(0.99,0.99,0.99),
                  b = c(0.1986572,0.1986572,0.1986572),
                  c = c(237.5,237.5,237.5),
                  d = c(1028.372, 1028.711, 1028.372),
                  e = c(2.46261, 2.986461, 2.46261),
                  f = c(-1,-1,-1),
                  g = c(9.8,9.8,9.8),
                  h = c(-54.97964, -51.65978, -54.97964),
                  i = c(0.03699588, -0.0375189, 0.03699588))

for(j in 1:length(dat$a)){
   a <- dat$a[j]
   b <- dat$b[j]
   c <- dat$c[j]
   d <- dat$d[j]
   e <- dat$e[j]
   #f: this should be solved by uniroot
   g <- dat$g[j]
   h <- dat$h[j]
   i <- dat$i[j]
   sol <- uniroot(func,c(0, 2000),extendInt = "yes") 
   dat$f[j] <- sol$root
   print(j)
}
```

Running above code, hit the below error:

```
[1] 1
Error in uniroot(func, c(0, 2000), extendInt = "yes") : 
      no sign change found in 1000 iterations
```

The code stopped at `j=1`, and did not go to `j=2 & 3`. Therefore, `dat$f` shows

```
> dat$f
[1] 1526.566   -1.000   -1.000
```

My goal is when `uniroot` hits an error in a given `j`, put `NA` in `dat$f[j]`, and continue the loop by the end.

If this works, `dat$f[1]` and `dat$f[3]` should have the same value (=1526.566) using the the above dataframe.

Please advise me on how to deal with the `uniroot` error.

Comment: This will depend on func which is missing from the question.  Please see the top of  the [tag:r] tag page and in particular example code should be complete and reproducible so anyone can copy and paste from the question into their R session and see the same error.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will add the details by tomorrow.

Comment: I re-created my question by including reproducible code in here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70216945/how-to-avoid-uniroot-error-that-stops-the-loop).

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions. Use the Edit button to edit your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question would work if the lower bound is set to 1 instead of 0. The problem is that if f is 0 then func is undefined since f is in the denominator.

While that is sufficient it is suggested you make these changes:

1. Use dat shown in the Note at the end ensuring that it does NOT include f.
2. define func more compactly as shown
3. use `try` to allow uniroot to continue to run even if there are errors (although there are none in t his example)
4. use a lower bound of 1 since func is undefined at 0
5. pass the jth row of dat to func using an argument of uniroot
6. place the results in res (or NA if that iteration fails) so there is no confusion as to what is input and what is output.

Use the more compact form of func shown and put the results in res.

```
func <- function(f, data) with(data, -a*b/c*0.5*d*e^2 + (d/f-1)*g*sin(h*(pi/180))-i)
nr <- nrow(dat)
res <- numeric(nr)
for(j in 1:nr){
   sol <- try(uniroot(func, c(1, 2000), data = dat[j, ], extendInt = "yes") )
   res[j] <- if (inherits(sol, "try-error")) NA else sol$root
   print(j)
}
## [1] 1
## [1] 2
## [1] 3
res
## [1] 1526.566 2014.476 1526.566
```

### Note

```
dat <- data.frame(a = c(0.99,0.99,0.99),
                  b = c(0.1986572,0.1986572,0.1986572),
                  c = c(237.5,237.5,237.5),
                  d = c(1028.372, 1028.711, 1028.372),
                  e = c(2.46261, 2.986461, 2.46261),
                  g = c(9.8,9.8,9.8),
                  h = c(-54.97964, -51.65978, -54.97964),
                  i = c(0.03699588, -0.0375189, 0.03699588))
```

Comment: This includes everything which I really need to know, with some very useful coding suggestions. Thank you very much.