# How to avoid uniroot error that stops the loop

Tags: r, try-catch, uniroot

I am running `uniroot` function in the loop, but hit an error and the code stopped. The code is as below;

```
func <-function(f) -a*b/c*0.5*d*e^2 + (d/f-1)*g*sin(h*(pi/180))-i
dat <- data.frame(a = c(0.99,0.99,0.99),
                  b = c(0.1986572,0.1986572,0.1986572),
                  c = c(237.5,237.5,237.5),
                  d = c(1028.372, 1028.711, 1028.372),
                  e = c(2.46261, 2.986461, 2.46261),
                  f = c(-1,-1,-1),
                  g = c(9.8,9.8,9.8),
                  h = c(-54.97964, -51.65978, -54.97964),
                  i = c(0.03699588, -0.0375189, 0.03699588))

for(j in 1:length(dat$a)){
   a <- dat$a[j]
   b <- dat$b[j]
   c <- dat$c[j]
   d <- dat$d[j]
   e <- dat$e[j]
   #f: this should be solved by uniroot
   g <- dat$g[j]
   h <- dat$h[j]
   i <- dat$i[j]
   sol <- uniroot(func,c(0, 2000),extendInt = "yes") 
   dat$f[j] <- sol$root
   print(j)
}
```

Running above code, hit the below error:

```
[1] 1
Error in uniroot(func, c(0, 2000), extendInt = "yes") : 
      no sign change found in 1000 iterations
```

The code stopped at j=1, and did not go to j=2 & 3. Therefore, `dat$f` shows

```
> dat$f
[1] 1526.566   -1.000   -1.000
```

My goal is when `uniroot` hits an error in a given `j`, put `NA` in `dat$f[j]`, and continue the loop by the end.

If this works, `dat$f[1]` and `dat$f[3]` should have the same value (=1526.566) using the the above dataframe.

Please advice me on how to deal with the uniroot error.

(This post was modified to include the code for being reproducible for everyone, as [suggested in my last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70200174/avoid-uniroot-error-in-the-loop-by-using-try-function))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I avoid uniroot error that stops the loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70200174/how-can-i-avoid-uniroot-error-that-stops-the-loop)

Comment: Yes, this answers my question. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to extend the range of the interval. For instance:

```
sol <- uniroot(func, c(0, 5000), extendInt = "yes")
```

Your code stops because within the range you defined `uniroot` did not find a solution

Comment: This works, and thank you very much for your suggestion.